# Why does mock server (restito) return nginx 302?

Tags: java, junit, jackson, jersey, mocking

I am using spring boot and want to create and test an Http service. The http service is the following:

```
@Service
public class HttpService {

  private Client client;

  @Autowired
  public HttpService(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  <T> T get(String url, MultivaluedMap params, Class<T> type) {

    ClientResponse response =
        client.resource(url)
              .queryParams(params)
              .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
              .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
              .get(ClientResponse.class);

    return response.getEntity(type);
  }
}
```

and my test is the following:

```
public class HttpServiceTests {

  private StubServer server;

  @Before
  public void start() {
    server = new StubServer().run();
    RestAssured.port = server.getPort();
  }

  @After
  public void stop() {
    server.stop();
  }

  @Test
  public void answerWith200() {
    ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
    clientConfig.getClasses().add(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);
    clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);

    Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);
    HttpService httpService = new HttpService(client);

    whenHttp(server).match(get("http://test.com")).then(status(HttpStatus.OK_200), stringContent("all ok"));

    String url = "http://test.com";
    String response = httpService.get(url, new MultivaluedMapImpl(), String.class);
    Assert.assertEquals("all ok", response);
  }
}
```

When running the test the actual response is:

```
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.11.13</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I also got the same response when I tried using the **Jadler** library.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your client hits some Nginx server instead of the service started by the mocking framework.

Check [restito examples](https://github.com/mkotsur/restito/blob/master/examples/popular-page/src/test/java/com/xebialabs/restito/examples/WikiClientTest.java#L40) more carefully to see which URL needs to be passed into your client so that it interacts with the Restito server rather than some real app.

Also note, that you don't need to pass the protocol and the domain name into `whenHttp(server).match(get("..."))`.